# Creating Barcode Image (with php?)

Tags: php, image, barcode

i've a particular question...
i need to create barcode image that will be used inside a pdf (created with php).
So i need to insert the image as a jpg|png|gif files inside the pdf... i can't insert a dynamic url as a source for the image.

I see (here but worldwid) there are plenty options that produce images like `<img src="myfile.php?code=12354353&code128" />`.... but i don't need a dynamic source, cause it will not work (already tested)...
what i need is the classic, html output like `<img src="myfilename.jpg|png|gif" />`.

Some hints on how to start this?

Comment: you realize that dynamic is EASILY converted to static? `ob_start(); render_barcode(); file_put_contents('myfilename.jpg', ob_end_clean());`? You need to get out of the mindsent of "find tool that does EXACTLY what I want", and get into the "find set of tools I can combine to do exactly what I want".

Comment: Thanks marc for your answer... as i said i don't need the "already-made-tool" but i need hints on how can i handle that... i'll take a look to the function you wrote...thanks ;)

Comment: i'm using the function you told me, and i just have to work with the "render_barcode();" function... i don't find example or info on manuals, what are the parameters? is a GD Lib function?